# Обрезать с строки все кроме email адреса

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка:

```
zobych - zobych@yandex.ru - Иван Забутырин - +79515543702
```

Как можно обрезать средствами php все кроме email адреса?

Comment: Не очевидно. Ваш ответ ничего мне не говорит. Прошу написать Вас, развернутый ответ. Благодарю!

Comment: `(explode(' - ', $str, 3))[1]` - не по теме?

Comment: @verstala, учите матчасть. Неочевидно - это PCRE согласно RFC822 & RFC1738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
<?php
$string = 'zobych - zobych@yandex.ru - Иван Забутырин - +79515543702';
$pattern = '/\S+@\S+/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>
```

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3fdb285fff52adfc122484fbcd908882f4cbb63)

Наличие любого пробельного символа (пробел, табуляция и т.п.) после e-mail (либо конца строки) - обязательно. На строке типа `'Василий Пупкин, v.pupkin@gmail.com, +7(123)456-78-90'` - засбоит.

Конечно, не сработает на экзотических адресах типа `"John Smith"@myhost.com` - но такие мало какой сервер поддерживает.